# Serializing a JSON response with dynamic keys

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I've got the following Json String which I need to serialize to POJO objects:

```
{"pump_6":{"name":"Pump 6","value":"tequila","pin":25},"pump_5":{"name":"Pump 5","value":"vodka","pin":24},"pump_4":{"name":"Pump 4","value":"oj","pin":23},"pump_2":{"name":"Pump 2","value":"gin","pin":27},"pump_1":{"name":"Pump 1","value":"rum","pin":17},"pump_3":{"name":"Pump 3","value":"coke","pin":22}}
```

As you see the keys are dynamic (pump_6, pump_5). I've tried different solutions but nothing seems te work to serialize it to a POJO.

I've tried things like this

```
for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
            String key = (String) o;
            System.out.println(key);
            Map<String, JsonElement> value = (Map<String, JsonElement>) map.get(key);
            System.out.println(value); //prints {Updated=week, Time=12pm} for first
            Pump pump = new Pump(value.get("name").toString(), value.get("value").toString(),  value.get("pin").getAsInt());
            arrayList.add(pump);
```

The following is my pump class

```
public class Pump {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("pin")
    public int pin;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String value;

    public Pump(String name, String value, int pin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.pin = pin;
    }

}
```

Anyone got an idea how to serialize this string to pojo's ?

Comment: Why not just use Gson?

Comment: Thanks, made a fix now. Posted solution above

Answer (score 1):

After the comment above about gson I found a solution to my problem

```
ArrayList<Pump> pumps = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Pump>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Pump> result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapType);

for(Map.Entry<String, Pump> entry : result.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().name);
    Pump pump = new Pump(entry.getValue().name, entry.getValue().value, entr.getValue().pin);
    pumps.add(pump);
}
```